# Shorter way to say: "regardless of whether it would..."

Tags: phrases

Is there a shorter way to say that phrase. As in a sentence like:

> Regardless of whether it would happen or not, all she wanted now was
>   to go back to her apartment.

Comment: "Regardless, all she wanted now ..."

Comment: When is this novel gona come out? Everyone here at ELU is eagerly waiting for it.

Comment: @Noah Ha, it's that sarcasm or you're talking seriously?

Comment: @janoChen Do you sense a note of sarcasm in my tone? I am serious and I think there are many others who are the same.

Comment: @Noah OK, I'll publish it on Amazon Kindle on Friday (it's a "long" short story.) People will be able to download it for free the first two days (the original price isn't much, though, just 0.99). Where should I post it by then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say  “Regardless of the outcome, all she wanted now was...” and have about the same meaning as your longer phrasing.   “Regardless of what the outcome might be, all she wanted now was...” is a  little more wordy but natural enough.  Note, the wording suggested in a comment, “Regardless, all she wanted now ...”, can be interpreted the same way as your original, but being less specific has alternative interpretations, ie need not mean the same as the original.

Another phrasing is “No matter what the outcome might be, all she wanted now was...”.  This is sometimes (probably not commonly) ellipsed to “No matter the outcome, all she wanted now was...” with the advantage of sidestepping the awkward mix of tenses in several of the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The beginning sounds a bit redundant overall, with the words "regardless" and "whether" having a similar meaning or concept.

Perhaps it would be better to say "Depending on what happens next" or "Depending on whatever happens".